# How can I invoke the same function for the Client/Server via WiFiP2P?

Tags: java, android

Maybe I don't understand why I want to ask the question, but I'm doing a small project for Android (I'm just starting with Android) in which basically is an application client / server communicating via WiFi Direct where through the server (or 'host' in this case) can set a stopwatch and then start it.  Then, after starting it I want the stopwatch to be displayed in the Client, the same for example if I want to pause it or stop it.  But I don't know how to do it to call for example the function 'start stopwatch' and that is reflected in the Client.  Maybe there's a very easy way and I can't think for myself, but since I can't think of anything, I've decided to seek help by this means.  PS: I've been following the WiFiP2P code that appears in Android Developers.